# Как назвать такой фрагмент кода?

Tags: c#, шаблоны-проектирования

```
private IMyType myProperty;

public IMyType MyProperty
{
    get
    {
        if(myProperty==null)
        {
            myProperty = AppKernel.Get<IMyType>();
        }
        return myProperty;
    }
}
```

Как называется эта техника (*создание экземпляра объекта в случае, если ссылка на объект пустая*)? Является ли это каким-то паттерном? Во многих примерах вижу такой подход. Интересно, имеет ли он какое-то название?

Comment: Lazy initialization, initialization on demand, delayed initialization, по-русски [отложенная инициализация](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Отложенная_инициализация).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это называется [ленивая инициализация](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_loading#Lazy_initialization).
Как правило такой подход используется, когда объект слишком громоздкий, и инициализировать все его поля сразу - отнимет время. С таким подходом поля будут инициализироваться во время первого обращения к ним. Это применяется в работе с базами данных, в частности, в ORM, например. Без крайней необходимости делать ленивую инициализацию не стоит.